# How to extend `Array.prototype` from remote lib in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm playing in `hackerrank` with pure JavaScript without extra arrayor math libs, unlike eg `python` and that's robustly. Whant to use `sugar.js` or `underscore`

I found here this solution, but how to extend the `Array.prototype` with this `res` data? And where is this the `sugar.min.js` in this `res`? Because it only consists of metadata.

```
require('http').get({
    host: 'cdnjs.cloudflare.com',
    path: '/ajax/libs/sugar/1.4.1/sugar.min.js'
  }, function(res) {
    // how to extend for example Array
    Array.prototype = res;
    var gs = ['big', 'pig', 'digg'].count(/g$/);
    console.log(gs);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a method to the prototype like this:

```
Array.prototype.count = function () {
  return this.length; //or whatever
}
```

but it looks like you're trying to use data from an AJAX request to modify a prototype. That seems a little...odd, but you can do it if you get a string representation of a function implementation over the network:

If we assume that 'res' returns this (I've no idea if it does or not):

```
{
    count: "return this.length;"
}
```

you could do this:

```
require('http').get({
    host: 'cdnjs.cloudflare.com',
    path: '/ajax/libs/sugar/1.4.1/sugar.min.js'
}, function(res) {
    var methods = JSON.parse(res);    
    Array.prototype.count = new Function(methods.counts);
    var gs = ['big', 'pig', 'digg'].count(/g$/);
    console.log(gs);
});
```

I've not tried it, but that should, in theory work. It's a spectacularly odd idea though (modifying your environment's built-ins with the results of network requests), so this may well not be what you mean.